# I want to display my phone number on windows 7 phone emulator

Tags: windows-phone-7

Hi currently i am learning windows 7 phone. I can display Device name, Manufacturer name  on  Emulator, but **i want display my phone number on Emulator for WP7**. Is it possible to show my phone number on Emulator.

tools i am using -Visual Studio 2010

Please guide me

Regards
Ramesh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to get the phone number of a phone through any of the available SDK APIs.